# how to execute a script with snmp (exec in snmpd.conf) in a solaris 10 zone

Tags: solaris, snmp

I am trying to execute a script through a SNMP GET using Net-Snmp included in the latest Solaris 10 (10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC).

I have a non-global zone which runs NET-SNMP version 5.0.9 patched to the last SMA patch (120272-26).

The zone responds to a snmpwalk but if I add
something like

```
exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.100 test /bin/echo "hello golem"
```

in /etc/snmp/conf/snmpd.conf
and restart:

```
svcadm restart sma
```

if I try to walk .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8 (UCD-SNMP-MIB::extTable) I get no objects.

In other similar cases I solved installing the version from sunfreeware.com
but it looks like the current version (netsnmp-5.4.2.1-sol10-sparc-local) is not working inside a zone.

Does anyone know how to enable the extTable tree?
What is really strange is that the man page for snmpd.conf shows the exec command
and the demon says it's capable to understand exec:

```
 prompt# /usr/sfw/sbin/snmpd -H 2>&1| grep exec
        exec                     [miboid] name program arguments
```

PS I get no hints from /var/log/snmpd.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer:

the proper config file is

```
/etc/sma/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

as I found out reading [this blog](http://all-unix.blogspot.com/2007/10/solarus-10-and-net-snmp.html) entry.
Adding the exec lines there gives the proper result.

It would be nice to know what the heck /etc/snmp/conf/snmpd.conf is used for
and why solaris people choose to use the other location as the main one.

Answer (score 1):

> Any errors in obtaining the information described above are reported by means of the 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.101.1.100 flag and the 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.101.1.101 text-string description.

Check content of `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.101.1.101` after checking `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.100`. You should also try adding `.` before your OID in the exec line, so:

`exec .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.100 test /bin/echo "hello golem"`

Comment: I get no answer from
snmpwalk  -Os -c public -v 1 myip .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8

while 
snmpwalk  -Os -c public -v 1 myip .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.101
gives
snmperrIndex.0 = INTEGER: 0
snmperrNames.0 = STRING: snmp
snmperrErrorFlag.0 = INTEGER: 0
snmperrErrMessage.0 = STRING: 
both with trailing dot and without in the snmpd.conf exec OID
(empty snmpd.log as usual)